# How to read form fields of indd file

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I have made a .indd file with some form fields in it.

Now I want to get all these fields through indesign script and manipulate its content

so that i can change the content of fields and apply these changes to .indd file.

Comment: like we do for form fields of pdf using itext...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have got this and able to get all fields of the doc.

```
var myDoc = app.open(File("fileName.indd"));
var allformFields = myDoc.formFields;
for(var i = 0; i < allformFields.length; i++){
    var tf = allformFields[i];
    alert(tf.name);
}
```